# What does a single vertical bar mean in ConditionalExpression?

Tags: conditional, assignment

I got the condition below as part of a `ConditionalExpression`. Those single vertical bars before and after $\frac{1}{k1}$ appear to be an absolute value but I don't recall seeing Mathematica ouput it like that. Also, I highlighted the character, pressed F1, and the program said that it could be `Alternatives`, `Or`, `Nand`, etc; but I did not see absolute value among the options. Which one is it?

[image]

Comment: it is `Alternatives`.

Comment: @kglr does that mean that at least one of the three equations needs to be a part of the reals for the expression to be true?

Comment: Lucas, `Element[a|b|c, dom]` means _**all**_  members of `{a,b,c}` belong to `dom`. Also, `Element[a|b|c, dom]` is equivalent to `Element[{a,b,c}, dom]`.  (see: [Element>> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) in the docs)